# Flutter: Automatically shrink font in TextField as user types

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am coding an app in which a set size TextField inside a Box should change font dynamically as the user types, so that all the inputted text fits in the original area

I have already tried auto_size_text but form what I could understand it only work with Text not with TextField. I have looked into controllers but couldn't find how to change the fontsize.